# Is there any relation between determinant of a matrix with positive entries and its largest eigenvalue?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Is there any relation between determinant of a matrix with positive entries and its largest eigenvalue ?

Comment: I think you have $det A\leqslant |\lambda|^n$ where $\lambda$ is the largest (in absolute value) eigenvalue and $n$ the size of $A$, but I have to check if some precondition is necessary (I think not).

Comment: @Evargalo - you don't need any additional conditions -- thats just using the fact that the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, and upper bounding each eigenvalue by the absolute value of the largest (in absolute value).

Answer (score 4):

Take the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & \epsilon \\ \epsilon & 1/a\end{bmatrix}$.

The determinant is $1-\epsilon^2$. Taking $a$ to be large and $\epsilon$ to be small, you see that the largest eigenvalue behaves roughly like $a$. So, the determinant and largest eigenvalue can be arbitrarily off.

As suggested in the comments by Evargalo, let $\lambda$ be the largest eigenvalue of $A$ in absolute value, and $A$ be a n x n matrix. Then, $det(A) \leq |\lambda|^n$. The proof is:Let $A$ have eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Then, $det(A)= \lambda_1\ldots\lambda_n$, so $\det(A) \leq |\det(A)| = |\lambda_1|\ldots|\lambda_n| \leq |\lambda|\ldots|\lambda|=|\lambda|^n$.

To see you can't do much better than the bound that Evargalo suggests, you can take matrices of the form 
$\begin{bmatrix} a & 1/a \\ 1/a & a\end{bmatrix}$
and look when $a$ is large. The determinant is $a^2 - \frac{1}{a^2} \approx a$ for large $a$, and the eigenvalues are $\frac{a^2 \pm 1}{a}\approx a$, so the determinant and square of the largest eigenvalue are close (both behave like $a^2$).

---

Note that if you had non-negative entries (the case pointed out by John Hughes in the comments), the problem is even more straightforward -- take $\epsilon=0$ in the first example, and $aI$ for the second example, and you see matrices with determinant $1$ with largest eigenvalue $a$ and a matrix with determinant $a^2$ and largest eigenvalue $a$, respectively.

Comment: So the largest eigenvalue can be an arbitrarily large multiple of the det; but as your comment on the question shows, the det cannot be an arbitraryly large multiple of the largest eigenvalue: it's bounded by $\lambda^n$ (where the matrix is $n \times n$), with the bound achieved by $nI$. (I"m adding this comment just to put all the info in one place.)